# Data migration from teradata to bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, teradata, database-migration

My requirement is to migrate data from teradata database to Google bigquery database where table structure and schema remains unchanged. Later, using the bigquery database, I want to generate reports.

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this?

Comment: have you googled it? What have you tried so far? refer [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: yeah, we can export teradata data into a flatfile and  we can import flat file in  bigquery. Manually i have created one  .csv file and using which i have created a table in bigquery. But i am having doubt like tables in teradata  are having different table structures, can we get the same table structure when we export into a flat file in bigquery , since i didnt get access to teradata yet to check that from my end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try TDCH to export data to Google Cloud Storage in Avro format. TDCH runs on top of hadoop and exports data in parallel. You can then import data from avro files into BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I was part of a team that addressed this issue in a Whitepaper.

> The white paper documents the process of migrating data from Teradata Database to Google BigQuery. It highlights several key areas to consider when planning a migration of this nature, including the rationale for Apache NiFi as the preferred data flow technology, pre-migration considerations, details of the migration phase, and post-migration best practices.

Link: [How To Migrate From Teradata To Google BigQuery](https://blog.pythian.com/migrate-teradata-google-bigquery/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also try to use cloud composer(apache airflow) or install apache airflow in instance. 
If you can open the ports from Teradata DB then you can run 'gsutil' command from there and schedule it via airflow/composer to run the jobs on daily basis. Its quick and you can leverage the scheduling capabilities of airflow.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery introduced Migration Service which is a comprehensive solution for migrating the data warehouse to BigQuery. It includes free to use tools that help with each phase of migration including assessment and planning to execution and verification.

**Reference:**

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/migration-intro